# Why did my sine wave turn into a square wave when written to a WAV file in Octave?

Tags: audio, octave

I am trying to use Octave to generate a pure sine wave. The code for the same is as follows:

`x = 10.*sin(2*pi*(300/16000)*(0:1:400));`
The sampling rate is 16000Hz, the sine wave is at 300 Hz. I write the above wave to a file using `wavwrite` like so:
`wavwrite(x, 16000, 16, "temp.wav")`

When I try to read it back into a variable, like so:
`y = wavread('temp.wav');`, I get square waves upon plotting `y`.
I have checked the sine wave and the period indicates a frequency of 300Hz.

How can a pure sine wave become a square wave on simply writing and reading? Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x` is being clipped and that is why `y` looks like a square wave. When writing `x` to disk using `wavwrite`, the samples of `x` are stored in 16 bits Q15 fixed-point format. That means your data must be in range `-1` to `+1` (in principle `+1` minus one lsb). Therefore, `x` must be normalized to be in this range before calling `wavwrite` in order to avoid clipping.

Comment: thanks! that was the problem.. funny thing.. i always neglect to look at such problems as normalization issues. :(

Comment: @Sriram I had the same problem(s) until I realized what was going on with the normalization. Although I seem to remember now all bit-widths needed normalization for writing to .wav files...

Comment: That should read "...NOT all bit-widths..." btw.